# javascript module with JQuery causing module functions to be undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a module called `ScrollToAnchor` that has a function called `goToTarget` that I will be able to call like `ScrollToAnchor.goToTarget(target);`

However it says that

> ScrollToAnchor.goToTarget is not a function

I think `ScrollToAnchor` is of type jQuery how I have it because of the `$`. Here is the code:

```
var ScrollToAnchor = $(function() {
  var headerHeight = 70;

  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      if (goToTarget(this.hash))
        return false;
    }
  });

  /*$('input[data-target]').click(function() {
          if (gotoTarget($(this).data("target")))
          return false;
  })*/

  var goToTarget = function(targetName) {
    var target = $(targetName);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name="' + targetName.slice(1) + '"]');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerHeight
      }, 1000);

      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  return {
    goToTarget: goToTarget
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? If i remove the `$` from `var ScrollToAnchor = $(function () {` then the jQuery inside `ScrollToAnchor` doesn't work.

But if I leave the `$` there then it thinks `ScrollToAnchor` is type jQuery and  `ScrollToAnchor.goToTarget` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(function() {...})`  is a short hand of `$( document ).ready( handler )`.

So the result of `$(function() {...})`  is a jQuery result set containing the `document` as element.

You are looking for event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])', function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    if (goToTarget(this.hash))
      return false;
  }
});
```

This will ensure that the `click` event will be use for all `a` element no matter when they have been added to the DOM and allows your to make your `goToTarget` available in the global scope in an easy way. Your final code will then look this way:

```
var ScrollToAnchor = (function() {
  var headerHeight = 70;

  // event handler with delegation
  $(document).on('click', 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])', function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      if (goToTarget(this.hash))
        return false;
    }
  });

  function goToTarget(targetName) {
    var target = $(targetName);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name="' + targetName.slice(1) + '"]');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerHeight
      }, 1000);

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  return {
    goToTarget: goToTarget
  }

}());
```

Using event delegation there is no need to wrap you whole code into a `$(function() {...})` and your `ScrollToAnchor` is public available.

Answer (score 1):

Turn ScrollToAnchor into a normal function. This function will be in the global scope:

```
window.ScrollToAnchorFactory = function () {
    var headerHeight = 70;
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            if (goToTarget(this.hash))
                return false;
        }
    });

    /*$('input[data-target]').click(function() {
            if (gotoTarget($(this).data("target")))
            return false;
    })*/

        var goToTarget = function (targetName) {
            var target = $(targetName);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name="' + targetName.slice(1) + '"]');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerHeight
                }, 1000);

                return true;
            }   

            return false;
        }

    return {
        goToTarget: goToTarget
    }
};
```

You could also use a module.export instead of putting this in the global scope, if you'd like to create a commonJS module out of this code.  That would allow you to require() it into other files (using Browserify to compile).

If you do decide to just keep `ScrollToAnchorFactory` in the global scope,  wherever you need to use scrollToAnchor.goToTarget (in the same file or a different one)...

```
$(function() {
    var scrollToAnchor = window.ScrollToAnchorFactory();
    // you can now use scrollToAnchor.goToTarget(target)
});
```

You'll want jQuery's DOM ready function wrapped around this part, so that `ScrollToAnchorFactory` doesn't try to init before your anchors are fully formed in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. How would I call `ScrollToAnchor.goToTarget(target)` in a different javascript file? Is there some kind of import statement? Because I'm getting `bootstrap_app.js:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: ScrollToAnchor is not defined`

Comment: Since you'd be putting `ScrollToAnchor` inside the scope of the jQuery DOM ready callback, it leaves the global scope.  One option would be to replace `var ScrollToAnchor` with `window.ScrollToAnchor`.  This would put ScrollToAnchor in the global scope, and make it available elsewhere.  This could lead to a race condition, though, if the other JS file tried to call `ScrollToAnchor` before the jQuery DOM ready function executed.  

I'm going to update my answer to help avoid this.